# Redirecting with check that user must be logged in with a LocalStorageService session variable Angular 4.3.1

Tags: angular, session

I'm new to Angular.

I want to restrict user's which are not logged in my app, I logged in user's information in a LocalStorageService session variable.

```js
    authenticate(x)
      {
        this.authService.authenticate(x)
        .subscribe(data => {
                this.session_data = data;
                //console.log(this.session_data[0]);
          if( data.user_email !== '')
          {
            const email: any = {'email': this.session_data[0].user_email}
            this.get_user_id(email);
            this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
          }
          //console.log(this.session_data);
          this.session.store('session_data', this.session_data);
          })
      }
```

By using `this.session_data = this.session.retrieve('session_data');`, I retrieve that variable in the dashboard page.

Now, I need to:

- empty the variable on logout
- check logged in status through that

I have gone through a lot of things for same, but I want to use the best practice for this. What should I use, and how should I implement it?

Here is my app.module.ts

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { URLSearchParams, Http, HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Ng2Webstorage } from 'ng2-webstorage';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { FormlistComponent } from './formlist/formlist.component';

import { ControlMessageComponent } from './control-message.component';
import { ValidationService } from './validation.service';
import { ParticlesModule } from 'angular-particle';

import { FillformComponent } from './fillform/fillform.component';
import { LandingPageComponent } from './landing-page/landing-page.component';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

export const routes: Routes = [
       { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
       { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
       //{ path: 'dashboard/user', component: DashboardComponent },
       { path: 'dashboard/formlist', component: FormlistComponent},
       { path: 'dashboard/fillform/:form_id', component: FillformComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    FormlistComponent,
    ControlMessageComponent,
    FillformComponent,
    LandingPageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    Ng2Webstorage,
    ParticlesModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [ValidationService,AuthService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

here is my logincomponent

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { LocalStorageService } from 'ng2-webstorage';

import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';


 @Component({
   selector: 'app-login',
   templateUrl: './login.component.html',
   styleUrls: [],
   providers: [AuthService]
 })
  export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
   filePath: string;
   session_data: any = {};
    message: string;
    user_id: any;
    userForm: any;
    myStyle: object = {};
    myParams: object = {};
    width: number = 100;
    height: number = 100;
 
    constructor( private authService: AuthService,
                 private router : Router,
                 private session: LocalStorageService,
                 private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { 
     this.filePath="../assets/img/user_img.png",
      this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'username': ['', Validators.required],
      /*'password': ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]]*/
      'password' : ['',[Validators.required]]
    });
    //console.log(this.userForm);
    }
    saveUser() {
    //console.log(this.userForm.value)
    if (this.userForm.dirty && this.userForm.valid) {
      //alert(`UserName: ${this.userForm.value.username} Password: ${this.userForm.value.password}`);
    }
  }

    ngOnInit()
    {
      console.log('it works... !!')

    
        this.myStyle = {
            'position': 'fixed',
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '100%',
            'z-index': 1,
            'top': 0,
            'left': 0,
            'right': 0,
            'bottom': 0,
        };
 
    this.myParams = {
            particles: {
                number: {
                    value: 50,
                },
                color: {
                    value: '#fffff'
                },
                shape: {
                    type: 'triangle',
                },
        }
    };
    }

    get_user_id(email)
    {
        this.authService.get_user_id(email)
        .subscribe(id => {
          //console.log(id.user_id)
           this.session_data[0].user_id = id.user_id;
        })
    }

    authenticate(x)
      {
        this.authService.authenticate(x)
        .subscribe(data => {
                this.session_data = data;
                //console.log(this.session_data[0]);
          if( data.user_email !== '')
          {
            const email: any = {'email': this.session_data[0].user_email}
            this.get_user_id(email);
            this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
          }
          //console.log(this.session_data);
          this.session.store('session_data', this.session_data);
          })
      }

  }
```

here is my service.

```js
// auth.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { URLSearchParams, Http, HttpModule, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Router, CanActivate }    from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private http: Http, private router: Router) { }

    canActivate()
    {
    if (this.isLoggedIn) { return true; }
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
      }


    authenticate(user_creds)
    {
      //console.log(user_creds);
      const header = new Headers();
      header.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      return this.http.post('http://localhost/valuesassessment/api/login/authenticate_login', user_creds, { headers: header })
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }

    get_user_id(email)
    {
      //console.log(email)
        const header = new Headers();
        header.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        return this.http.post('http://localhost/valuesassessment/api/forms/get_user_id', email, { headers: header })
        .map((id: Response) => id.json());
    }

    get_forms_to_fill(user_id)
    {
        //console.log(user_id)
        const header = new Headers();
        header.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        return this.http.post('http://localhost/valuesassessment/api/forms/get_forms_to_fill', user_id, { headers: header })
        .map((form_ids: Response) => form_ids.json());
    }

    get_questions()
    {
      const header = new Headers();
      header.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      return this.http.post('http://localhost/valuesassessment/api/forms/fetch_questions', {}, { headers: header })
      .map((questions: Response) => questions.json());
    }

    submit_score(score)
    {
      const header = new Headers();
      header.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      return this.http.post('http://localhost/valuesassessment/api/forms/submit_scores', score, { headers: header })
      .map((scores: Response) => scores.json());
    }

    logout(LSkey)
    {
      const header = new Headers();
        header.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        return this.http.post('http://localhost/valuesassessment/api/login/logout', LSkey, { headers: header })
        .map((logout: Response) => logout.json());
    }

}
```

here is my dashboard component

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { LocalStorageService } from 'ng2-webstorage';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: []
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
 logoIMG: string;
 logoutIMG: string;
 userIMG: string;
 organisationIMG: string;
 empathyIMG: string;
 accountabilityIMG: string;
 message: string;
 userEmail: string;
   session_data: any = {};
   user_image_url: string = "https://intranetlive.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/uploads/profile/220x220/";
   form_details: any ={};

   constructor( private router : Router, private session: LocalStorageService, private authService: AuthService ) {
    this.logoIMG = "../assets/img/logo.svg"
    this.logoutIMG = "../assets/img/logout.svg"
    this.userIMG = this.userIMG
    this.organisationIMG = "../../assets/img/ic-organization.png"
    this.empathyIMG = "../../assets/img/ic-empathy.png"
    this.accountabilityIMG = "../../assets/img/ic-accountability.png"
    this.session_data = this.session.retrieve('session_data');
    console.log(this.session_data)
   }
   ngOnInit()
   {
    if (this.session_data[0].length == 0)
    {
     console.log('It`s on Dashboard...!!')
     this.router.navigate(['']);
    }
    //this.userIMG = this.user_image_url+this.session_data[0].user_profile_picture
    console.log(this.session_data)
   }
    go_to_fromsList()
    {
    this.get_forms_to_fill()
     this.router.navigate(['dashboard/formlist']);

    }   
   
   get_forms_to_fill()
      {
       const user_id: any = {'user_id': this.session_data[0].user_id}
        this.authService.get_forms_to_fill(user_id)
        .subscribe(form_details => {
       //console.log(form_details)
       this.session.store('form_detail', form_details);
        })
      }

      logout()
      {
       const LSkey: any = {'LSkey': this.session_data.session_key}
       this.authService.logout(LSkey)
       .subscribe(logout => {
        //console.log(logout.logged_out)
        if(logout.logged_out == true)
        {
         this.session.clear();
         this.session.store('session_data', {});
         this.router.navigate([''])
        }
       })
       console.log(this.session)
       console.log(this.session_data)
      }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should try and Implement `Angular Guards` for this scenario .[Documenation](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards)

There are four different guard types we can use to protect our routes:

> CanActivate - Decides if a route can be activated
>
> CanActivateChild - Decides if children routes of a route can be
>   activated
>
> CanDeactivate - Decides if a route can be deactivated
>
> CanLoad - Decides if a module can be loaded lazily

Live Implementation of [guards](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/guard)

Comment: Thanks, this helps but does't solve my problem as i can't use CanActivate in my app.module.ts....  In my app, i'm using only 1 service throughout the app and  i don't know how to use CanActivate their, it's giving errors

Comment: Why do you want a guard for app module

Comment: i want the guard for routing but as per you commented, i have to use CanActivate in my service file, how would i implement it their

Comment: You use guards for component not services

Comment: i have updated the questions and have given my code their, which would help you understand what i want to do,  Will i have to create some new component,service or module or i can achieve what i want in the same files.    Thanks for the help

Comment: I donot understand actually what you want you want to pass paramters conditonally to services you can check in guard and even so you can use resolve if you want to call with different routes . you dnt use gaurds for routes only templates i:e components

Comment: thanks for the answer i have applied CanActivate and it works just fine and yes i was wrong as i was using it for service,  It works fine for components. Thanks again @ rahul